# Geometry Nodes: Popping Peas on a Pan (or even popcorn)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I tried to make balls to bounce nicely on a flat surface, as if you were popping some popcorn. But it gets complicated. How to do it properly?

This is basically what I would like an individual pea to behave:

[image]

And this is how multiple ones should behave:

[image]

- Especially small bounces should happen faster, tall bounces should take more time
- I can see here would be room to make a separate **popcorn** version, in where the corn kernels would sit still and then change form into a popcorn and do one bounce. Could be cool :)

A good base .blend to start with:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my take on it ! That was the first time I actually played with the simulation zone feature and I have to say it resembles the old Animation Nodes system a lot which I love. Not having to mess with named attributes and such is also great. Cheers.

[image]

And the node tree

[image]

I didn't use Distribute on Faces because the performance is abysmal with big areas, basically not usable for real time simulation. I distributed the points on the disk with a fast method which unfortunately does not ensure a homogeneous distribution. Spheres tend to bounce more towards the center as a result.

[image]

then a simulation zone with a start and end position as parameters.

[image]

Each frame every point is moved on a 2D plane towards its current target on the disk

[image]

[image]

When the target is reached, a new random point on the disk is chosen at random as the target, and the previous target becomes the current jump start.

[image]

The bounce is simply a sine wave that's calculated by getting the current interpolation between the start and the end of jump. Short jumps go lower than long jumps.

[image]

[image]

Finally everything is instanced, and joined.

[image]

And the .blend (V4.02)

[image]

PS here's what 1800 spheres look like on a 4m wide plate

[image]

Comment: Muahahaa! That is so cool :) I have some learning to do! Thank you so much!